# series $\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^n}$ convergences?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Try to undestand this series:
$$\sum\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^n}$$

So I'm found a limit

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^n}{(n+1)^n} = (\frac{n}{n+1})^n = (\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}})^n = \frac{1}{e}$$

so limit > 0, and our series maybe convergences, but what is next? I'm failed with root test (equal 1)
May be ratio test?

Comment: Ohhhh, thx! I didn't carefully read the definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* If $\lim a_n \ne 0$, then $\sum a_n$ does not converge.